# Excessive RAM use by Datatable Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I need to extract data from a DB2 database and then display them in a Datatable Jquery. I have problems of slowness in the view, already with a 500 records and especially in this case I see that Chrome has a usage of RAM equal to more than 1 GB, which does not seem absolutely normal. Once the data is displayed, export to excel takes up only about 500 kb.

I place the AJAX call to a function that performs the database query and places the results in an array, then converted into JSON and displayed in the datatable by the caller.

Maybe something wrong? There is a method to speed up this process?

Thank you
Roberto R.

Comment: Did you set the deferred rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error. The problem was in the way I showed the data, with a loop that added each line to the datatable by fnAddData.

This worked well with little data to display, but exhausted all the PC's RAM if the lines exceeded the 100.

Now step to the function all the JSON in once time and it works much better.